# Derivative is again in Lie algebra.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose $H$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$, with corresponding Lie algebras $\mathfrak{h}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$.  Let  $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ and $Y \in \mathfrak{h}$.

Can we say the following, if so, why?
$$ Ad_{e^{tX}}(Y) \in \mathfrak h\implies \left. \dfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}Ad_{e^{tX}}(Y) \in \mathfrak h.$$

Comment: Maybe you should write out what it means to take the derivative. Then the answer should come naturally to you.

Comment: Yeah, basically since a smooth curve in $\mathfrak{g}$  is a smooth curve in $\mathfrak{h}$ and the tangent space of $\mathfrak{h}$  is again $\mathfrak{h}$, lol.

Comment: Yes, that’s it. But you don't need to think about tangent spaces here. You just take the derivative of a smooth map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$.